# Memcache backup or a better way to store user session/activity and dump into DB once?

Tags: database, session, android-activity, memcached

I need to store user sessions when they login to my website. Plan it this:
Store user session in memcache when user signs in.
All user activities are tracked so log all that in memcache only so i dont have to hit the DB every second writing "A shared a photo" "A clicked on a link.."
When user logs off OR the connect is cut then write an edt time and copy all data to the DB.

Now problem is if memcache crashes then all this data gets lost. So what is the work around?
Do note: I am tracking all user activity including mouse clicks, so i cannot be writing to the DB every second for each user hence i was suggested to use memcache but i am open too other ideas also.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is pretty much why we wrote [membase](http://www.membase.com/products-and-services/overview) in the first place.

Comment: From what i read it looks to be more for people who have tons of nodes not 1-2 nodes. Or is this beneficial for 1-2 nodes also?

Comment: 2-5 is plenty common.  It's even better when you have the 2 and you decide you suddenly need to add a third and you don't have to rip everything apart and put it back together.  One also works, but you have no redundancy so growing from 1-2 actually reduces throughput since you will suddenly have replicas (but you get it back for each one after that).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [memcachedb](http://memcachedb.org/) but have moved to [redis](http://redis.io/) and it rocks!

Comment: Why is redis better? Was there more effort in learning the new technology?